# Use PHP to extract values from database and pass the results as a variable to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

I have a JS/Html file and a PHP script. The PHP file creates a database connection and returns the result of the DB query.

The html page uses an ajax request to get the data and echos it back to the html page - but it is returned as text (xmlhttp.responseText), which I can display, but can't easily manipulate.

I would like to return the data as an array that I can process in JavaScript.

Is there a way for an ajax request to include the response as a variable, instead of as raw text?

If I can provide more information to make it easier to answer, let me know!

thanks!

Comment: Look into the JSON formatting. Php can echo your variables using `json_encode()`, which javascript can read and decode.

Comment: What about returning the response as XML with xmlhttp.responseXML? That allows you to access the individual nodes if the returned data is valid xml. The JSON option is probably easier though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [PHP, JSON and JavaScript usage](http://ditio.net/2008/07/17/php-json-and-javascript-usage/)